# Is there a term to describe a 16 bit and 32 bit value?

Tags: terminology

In terminology, a 4 bit is nibble and 8 bit is byte. However, for bigger things I have scene the term "word" being used e.g in the windows header file WORD is 16 bits while DWORD which stands for double word is 32 bits. However, I have not yet scene a universal term like nibble and byte.

Often we deal with systems that have 16 bit, 32 bit or even 64 bit data buses. So what we read would have a long description like "4 byte word" or "8 byte word".

Is there a specific name to refer to 16 bit, 32 bit and 64 bit values like we have nibble and byte for smaller values?

Answer (score 1):

"plyte" and "dyner" have been proposed, but never really caught on.